# Skip makefile dependency generation for certain targets (e.g. `clean`)

Tags: makefile, dependencies, debian, gnu-make

I have several C and C++ projects that all follow a basic structure I've been using for a while now. My source files go in `src/*.c`, intermediate files in `obj/*.[do]`, and the actual executable in the top level directory.

My makefiles follow roughly this template:

```
# The final executable
TARGET := something
# Source files (without src/)
INPUTS := foo.c bar.c baz.c

# OBJECTS will contain: obj/foo.o obj/bar.o obj/baz.o
OBJECTS := $(INPUTS:%.cpp=obj/%.o)
# DEPFILES will contain: obj/foo.d obj/bar.d obj/baz.d
DEPFILES := $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)

all: $(TARGET)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

obj/%.d: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M -MF $@ -MT $(@:%.d=%.o) $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(DEPFILES) $(RPOFILES) $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

Now I'm at the point where I'm packaging this for a Debian system. I'm using `debuild` to build the Debian source package, and `pbuilder` to build the binary package. The `debuild` step only has to execute the `clean` target, but even this causes the dependency files to be generated and included.

In short, my question is really: **Can I somehow prevent make from generating dependencies when all I want is to run the `clean` target?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is easy, don't `-include` generated files under clean:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    -include $(DEPFILES)
endif
```